# Linq query C# How to add condition below query

Tags: c#, linq, datatable, ado.net

In Datatable returns muliple rows , I want to get value from condtion based on

```
public string EHSStatus(long ProjectId, DataTable _ehs, long _questionid)
    {

        string _ehsstatus = string.Empty;
        try
        {

            string _responsevalue = (from _x in _ehs.AsEnumerable()
                                  select _x.Field<string>("EhsStatus")).FirstOrDefault();


            if (_responsevalue != null)
            {
                if (_responsevalue.Contains("Met"))
                {
```

Here , I want to include one condtion && questionid how to add this.

Comment: it's unclear exactly what you're after. please elaborate...

Comment: You can add it to the linq query syntax, which you already have, with a `where` condition, but you should probably add it to your sql query which you use to populate your datatable. Show us more code and give us more details in your question.

Comment: Use [a `where` clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/where-clause)?

Comment: What @OusmaneD. (Ousmane Dembélé?) said :)

Comment: @MarkCiliaVincenti a bit off-topic... although we got the same name no I am not the french winger ^_^.

Answer (score 1):

This code can help you:

```
    var ehs = _ehs.AsEnumerable();
    var responsevalue = ehs.where(q => q.Field<"pId"> == ProjectId && q.Field<"qId"> == _questionid)
.select(k => k.Field<string>("EhsStatus").FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a where clause as commented by @Silvermind. Replace pID and qID with the real names of the fields in your datatable.

```
string _responsevalue = (from DataRow _x in _ehs.AsEnumerable()
                         where _x.Field<long>("pID") == ProjectId && _x.Field<long>("qID") == _questionid 
                         select _x.Field<string>("EhsStatus").FirstOrDefault()).ToString();
```